# DNS subdomain syntax

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have a subdomain bonify.archaeolabs.nl it points to my servers ipaddress (DNS) and shows the www.archaeolabs.nl page. I have another root directory for bonify.archaeolabs.nl, I have a bonify.archaeolabs.nl.conf file with the following:

```
<virtualhost*: 80>
ServerAdmin email_address
ServerName bonify.archaeolabs.nl
ServerAlias bonify.archaeolabs.nl
DocumentRoot /path/to/bonify.archaeolabs.nl

<Directory "/path/to/bonify.archaeolabs.nl/">
  Option FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Am I close or barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: as far as I know 'ServerName' and 'ServerAkias' must be unique. Rest should work, but I currently can´t verify it while on vacation.

Comment: So I could just delete the alias line?

Comment: yes, the alias is for different domains and/or subdomains which should be routed to the same document root.

Comment: If the page is still not reachable you may find additional infos in the error or access log of you apache server which might help to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking through them since apache wont restart following these edits

Comment: Ok, fixed apache (a2dissite then restart, a2ensite and restart again) but the bonify url is still redirecting to the archaeolabs directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I needed to add the ipaddress and subdomain to the /etc/hosts file, now it works like a charm!